# Getting blank page on submitting form

Tags: php

I am pretty new to PHP and I am obtaining a blank page while submitting a form. Also no data is being added onto the database. Each time an expense record is added, the values for amount, date, id(user id) and cat_id should be added into the `myexpense` table.

**Database**
[image: my database structure]

**HTML**

```
<form action="newexpense.php" method="post">

    <label for="amount"><i class="fas fa-money-bill"></i>&nbsp;<strong>Amount (Rs)</strong></label><br>
    <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="Input the amount spent"><br><br> 

    <p><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list"></i>&nbsp;<strong>Please select the category:</strong></p>
    <input type="radio" id="cat1" name="category" value="Car">
    <label for="cat1">Car</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="cat2" name="category" value="Gifts">
    <label for="cat2">Gifts</label><br>  
    <input type="radio" id="cat3" name="category" value="Groceries">
    <label for="cat3">Groceries</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="cat4" name="category" value="House">
    <label for="cat4">House</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="cat5" name="category" value="Medicine">
    <label for="cat5">Medicine</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="cat6" name="category" value="Travel">
    <label for="cat6">Travel</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="cat7" name="category" value="Other">
    <label for="cat7">Other</label><br><br>  

    <label for="date"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>&nbsp;<strong>Date</strong></label><br>
    <input type="date" id="date" name="date"><br><br><br> 
    
    <p class="b-option">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Expense" class="loginbtn">
    </p>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

include "db.php";

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $amount = $_POST["amount"];
    $date = $_POST["date"];
    $category = $_POST["category"];      

    $cat_id = "";
    switch($category) {
      case "Car":
        return $cat_id = 1;
        break;
      case "Gifts":
        return $cat_id = 2;
        break;
      case "Groceries":
        return $cat_id = 3;
        break;
    }
  
  
    $sql = "INSERT INTO myexpense (amount, date, id, cat_id)
    VALUES ('".$amount."', '".$date."', '".$_SESSION['id']."', '".$cat_id."')";
  
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
      header("location: newexpensesuccess.php");
    }else {
      $message = "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
      
  }
  
?>
```

Comment: You are open for [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a `return` in your `switch` statement, no code below it will be executed, so you query won't execute too. Remove the return statements before the variable assignments. Also the last `break` is redundant.

```
switch($category) {
    case "Car":
        $cat_id = 1;
        break;
    case "Gifts":
        $cat_id = 2;
        break;
    case "Groceries":
        $cat_id = 3;
}
```

But I don't like `switch` statements so much. Imagine your list of categories becomes longer, than you would get a really long `switch` block.

My approach would be to use an array with the categories and iterate over them in a loop.

```
$catMap = [ 'Car' => 1, 'Gifts' => 2, 'Groceries' => 3 ];

foreach ( $catMap as $name => $id ) {
    if ( $name === $category ) {
        $cat_id = $id;
        break;
    }
}
```

With this method the code is shorter, but also more dynamic. You only have to modify the array to add more categories.

Answer (score 0):

In your script you have a `switch` case statement. And the case will be true you assign the variable `$cat_id = xxxx;` Then you set return. The `return` statement aborts the script at this point. Use instead break; And that's the reason why you don't get any output. The correct use of the `switch`-case command is:

```
switch($var) {
  case '1': 
       $var = 'something';
       break;
  case '2': 
       $var = 'something';
       break;
  default: 
       // do something to avoid error or something else.
       $var = 'default Value';
       // or
       exit(); // because nothing matched
```

Comment: Why the `exit` in the default state though

Comment: @DarkBee It can be anything. Maybe assign a default value to $var. It was only a example. And you are right, a exit in production wouldn´t be good.

Comment: @Arvin You welcome! If it was helpful, it's a good sign on Stackoverflow to leave an Upvote and/or an
Accept for the helpful answers.

Comment: @KrassVerpeilt Unfortunately, I cannot upvote due to low reputation but I did accept. Thanks again

Comment: @Arvin Unfortunately i dont see a upvote or accetped. Can you try again, please?